# Microsoft Teams: unable to load an app sometimes because of “There was a problem reaching this app” error, sometimes it works

Tags: angular, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I had created a custom app and upload a manifest file on ms teams. when I try to open it, it displays the below error sometimes, and sometimes it works fine. I googled it and found some solution, I gave fix which is `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess()` as "showLoadingIndicator": true in manifest file. but this is still not fixed. I am facing it when I try to hit the app inside ms teams.

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 1):

We have referred the documentation shared by Hilton and we have tested both the functions notifySuccess() and notifyAppLoaded().
Below are the differences:

- notifyAppLoaded() - To notify app loaded to hide loading indicator.
- notifySuccess() - To notify app Initialization success and ready for user interaction.

Could you please try with notifyAppLoaded() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.appinitialization?view=msteams-client-js-latest), you'll see that you actually need to call `notifyAppLoaded` to 'hide loading indicator'.