# There is a problem reaching the app - SDK initialization timed out

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

Trying to publish a new manifest on our app to the store. When the MS people from India are trying to validate they are getting "There is a problem reaching the app".

They use the same APP as in production to test the manifest so all of our customer is using the same "code".

The teams application is written in Vue SPA.
After loading Vue i do:

await this.microsoftTeams.app.initialize();
and directly after this.microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyAppLoaded();

Before i had Vue loading after initialize() and after Vue was finished loading i did notifyAppLoaded() but it did not change anything to any of this and none of our customers has any issues about this.

Only change thing changed in manifest is that i have added "showLoadingIndicator": true

I could see the error on their video and its "SDK initialization timed out".
Is there anything i can do to fix this?
I have the same manifest on my local dev app and on our test setup for x amount of people to use/test and none of us has this issue with same manifest.

Cannot reproduce in any way im kinda lost here. Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Can you share your deployed manifest zip package, so that we can check once from our end

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392907/microsoft-teams-unable-to-load-an-app-sometimes-because-of-there-was-a-problem) might be useful, but basically I'd suggest turning off the loading indicator and removing the `notifyAppLoaded`, at least for now. If you really want one, you can consider just using your own loading indicator.

Comment: This solved the problem for them.